# highcharts not showing decimal points coming from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, highcharts

i am creating a simple line highchart with data coming from an external xml file, but i can't get it to show decimal points, for example, xml returns 25.6, 25.1,25.9 and the chart puts the line in 25 and tooltip show 25 instead of 25.6 and so.
Here is the code:

```
function chart1(start, end) {

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart1',
        type: 'line'
    },
    colors: ['#D9CDB6'],
    title: {
        text: 'Data coming from A4 table'
    },
     tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,',')
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
formatter: function () {
    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
}
}, 
xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volts'
        },
        labels: {
       format: '{value:.2f}'}
    },

    series: []
};
// Load the data from the XML file 
$.get('chart1data.php?start=' + start + '&end=' + end, function(xml) {

    // Split the lines
    var $xml = $(xml);

    // push categories
    $xml.find('categories item').each(function(i, category) {
        options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
    });

    // push series
    $xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
        var seriesOptions = {
            name: $(series).find('name').text(),
            data: []
        };

        // push data points
        $(series).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
            seriesOptions.data.push(
                    parseInt($(point).text())
                    );
        });

        // add it to the options
        options.series.push(seriesOptions);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}
```

And chart1data returns this:

```
<chart><categories><item>2014-10-17 05:00:09</item><item>2014-10-19 03:01:01</item><item>2014-10-19 03:02:04</item><item>2014-10-19 03:03:06</item><item>2014-10-19 02:04:51</item><item>2014-10-19 02:05:04</item><item>2014-10-17 05:06:52</item><item>2014-10-17 05:07:08</item><item>2014-10-17 05:08:12</item><item>2014-10-19 02:09:04</item><item>2014-10-19 02:10:05</item><item>2014-10-19 02:11:01</item><item>2014-10-19 02:12:03</item><item>2014-10-19 02:13:06</item><item>2014-10-19 02:14:01</item><item>2014-10-18 23:15:29</item><item>2014-10-18 23:16:03</item><item>2014-10-18 23:17:05</item><item>2014-10-18 13:18:15</item><item>2014-10-18 13:19:06</item><item>2014-10-18 13:20:03</item><item>2014-10-18 13:21:07</item><item>2014-09-29 19:22:55</item><item>2014-09-29 19:23:05</item><item>2014-10-18 23:24:00</item><item>2014-10-18 23:25:03</item><item>2014-10-18 23:26:05</item><item>2014-10-18 23:27:00</item><item>2014-10-18 23:28:02</item><item>2014-10-18 23:29:05</item><item>2014-10-18 23:30:00</item><item>2014-10-18 23:31:02</item><item>2014-10-18 12:32:39</item><item>2014-10-18 12:33:10</item><item>2014-09-29 19:34:42</item><item>2014-09-29 19:35:10</item><item>2014-10-18 12:36:01</item><item>2014-10-18 12:37:00</item><item>2014-10-18 23:38:02</item><item>2014-10-18 12:39:00</item><item>2014-10-18 12:40:01</item><item>2014-10-17 04:41:51</item><item>2014-10-17 04:42:07</item><item>2014-10-17 04:43:11</item><item>2014-10-17 04:44:00</item><item>2014-10-17 04:45:03</item><item>2014-10-17 04:46:07</item><item>2014-09-29 19:47:11</item><item>2014-10-17 04:48:03</item><item>2014-10-17 04:49:13</item><item>2014-10-17 04:50:01</item><item>2014-10-17 04:51:05</item><item>2014-10-17 04:52:09</item><item>2014-10-17 04:53:12</item><item>2014-10-17 04:54:00</item><item>2014-10-17 04:55:10</item><item>2014-10-17 04:56:14</item><item>2014-10-17 04:57:02</item><item>2014-10-17 04:58:00</item><item>2014-10-17 04:59:59</item></categories><series><name>A4</name><data><point>25,60</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,64</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,64</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,56</point><point>25,58</point><point>25,58</point><point>25,55</point><point>25,58</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,58</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,58</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,63</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,60</point><point>25,61</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,62</point><point>25,66</point><point>25,59</point><point>25,63</point></data></series></chart>
```

Tried changing , to . as decimal separator but nothing happened.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing parseInt($(point).text()) into parseFloat($(point).text())